# How to call back on the calling class to access a variable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am using constructor dependency injection. In my main class(Analyzer class) I inject all the other classes as services. The Analyzer class then calls a method in the injected class (peopleService class). The method returns a peoples List. But I need to store some other information back in the caller class (Analyzer class). I have created a static IList inside Analyzer class to store it, but I do not know who to call back to the Analyser class's IList to store back data from the method in peopleService class. Do I create a instance of the Analyzer class inside the peopleSerivce class or is there a proper way for it. Please advise on the correct way.

```
//---- analyzer class ----
private static readonly List<string> MissingItemsInMapping = new List<string>();

public IList<string> MissingItemsInMappingsList => MissingItemsInMapping;
private readonly IPeopleService _peopleService;

//constructor
public Analyzer(IPeopleService peopleService)

{
   _peopleService = peopleService;
}

//calling people service method
var people = _peopleService.GetPeopleForEvent(category, date);

//---- People class ----
public IList<People> GetPeopleForEvent(string category, DateTime date)
{
  var ppl = new List<People>();
  If()
  {
    //some logic

    return ppl;
  }
  else
  {
    // This is where I need to access and send back data into MissingItemsInMapping list of Analayzer class's. It will be later used to send some mail
    // -- How to do this? --
    return new List<People>(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a new parameter to `GetPeopleForEvent`.

Comment: Why don't you simply store the return value of the service method on a `List<string>` instance variable in your `Analyzer` class? If the service knows which items are missing, it should return this information to the caller. The service shouldn't have any reference to the caller.

Comment: @sm101 I don't see a method calling people, only a variable that stores the result. Is this the actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code never uses a method that invokes the service. You're using a field. If that's the intended usage, then here's a possible solution.

```
//---- analyzer class ----
private static List<string> MissingItemsInMapping = new List<string>();

public IList<string> MissingItemsInMappingsList => MissingItemsInMapping;
private readonly IPeopleService _peopleService;

//constructor
public Analyzer(IPeopleService peopleService)

{
   _peopleService = peopleService;
}

//calling people service method
var people = _peopleService.GetPeopleForEvent(category, date, MissingItemsInMapping);

//---- People class ----
public IList<People> GetPeopleForEvent(string category, DateTime date, List<string> information)
{
  var ppl = new List<People>();
  If()
  {
    //some logic

    return ppl;
  }
  else
  {
    // You have access to MissingItemsInMapping here, use .Add, or whatever suits you
    // to add/modify the list.
    return information;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's the way. Now I get it since its a reference type I don't have to pass it back. Excellent

Comment: @sm101 Yeah, objects are always passed by reference.